# Laravel cannot get more than 15k records

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5.1

I have a very simple query to get records from the database:

```php
\DB::table("table")->get();
```

When I try to get more than ±145000 records from the database I am getting:
`500 server error`.

The code like:

```php
\DB::table("table")->take(14500)->get();
```

although works. When I try to get more than 15k I get the error immediately without any loading or further information.
I cannot get any more info from logs as well. An odd thing is that when I write that code to tinker - I can get all records. (with eloquent works the same)

Comment: Have you checked to see what is the error in your log?

Comment: are you on a local DB or a live DB?  Also did you say that eloquent works properly?

Comment: @ChinLeung there is no error in the logs.

Comment: @BradGoldsmith I am on live DB. When using eloquent the same error appears.

Comment: Can you try `select * from yourtable limit 15000` directly in postgresql?

Comment: @cbaconnier sure thing. I tried it and it does work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd check your error log you will most likely see something along the lines of:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 54 bytes)
```

It would be better to [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#chunking-results) your results instead of loading it all at once to memory

```
\DB::table("table")->chunk(500, function($results) {
    foreach($results as $result) {
       do your thing
    }    
});
```

Comment: I will try it. I was just curious how is it possible not to work in code but in tinker it does. I cannot see any error but I can try to increase allowed memory to see if it was the problem.
The chunks are good idea though. I will use it. Thank you.

Comment: @Epsilon47 Tinker runs in the CLI, which typically has no memory limit. The webserver typically has a memory limit of a few hundred megabytes. Don't increase memory, it'll just delay the problem.

Comment: @Epsilon47 in tinker you run with command line php, which doesn't have a memory or timeout limit.

Comment: Oh, okay, that's useful to know. The chunks will do the work

Comment: @Epsilon47 yea, it will do the work, and it will allow PHP to clear memory in between because of the function scope end. But, if you need a counter or something to pass around you might have to pass the variables by reference `chunk(500, function($results) use (&$render, &$counter, $pagename) { /*dostuff*/ });`

Comment: @Tschallacka Yep. I have done it that way it it works nicely. Than you:)

Comment: @Tschallacka i have also this issue. but can u give me a sugession for fix this issue instead of using increase memory size or chunk?

Comment: @RuwanthaSameera those are literally the two options available. Just put the code you loop through within the chunk code

Comment: @Tschallacka in this case i cant add chunk.all the records get and need to process.

Comment: @RuwanthaSameera with chunking it does process everything. In the first call of the callback records 0-99 then 100-199 etc... if you have a counter or object you need to record to you can use a use to pass along variables `$query->chunk(100, function($results) use (&$counter, &$someotherobject){foreach($results as $result){$counter++;//your code here}}`